# Why eclipse4.6 comes with the JavaScript editor to lose the smart tips，Is this the bug eclipse4.6?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor

[image][This is the JavaScript eclipse4.6 editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEJ9O.png)

Comment: The javascript editing tools in the following versions of eclipse 4.6 are supported for smart tips, Just eclipse 4.6 version does not support the intelligent tips, why?